# Generating REST API doc using swagger 0.9.1 for Spring MVC project

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui

For my project,I want to generate REST API doc using swagger.I found one example app [here](https://github.com/ufasoli/spring-mvc-swagger-tutorial)

But this example is using 0.5.2 version of swagger-springmvc.

This version is not compatible with my Spring project.

could someone please guide me about how to integrate swagger 0.9.1 in spring MVC?

Note : Mine is not a spring boot app.

Answer (score 1):

Adrian, one of the contributors to swagger-springmvc, has a repository with sample projects.

You can find the repository here - https://github.com/adrianbk/swagger-springmvc-demo.

By the way, the link to that is available at the main README of the swagger-springmvc project.

Comment: webron,thanks for ur recommendation.The demo project uses gradle.But in my project,I am using Maven.So I want settings related to maven.

Comment: When it comes to the project architecture, gradle or maven make no difference. The project sample itself is the same.

Comment: All the instructions for maven are available [here](https://github.com/martypitt/swagger-springmvc). The readme explains how to set up the plugin for various scenarios. Let us know via the [issues](https://github.com/martypitt/swagger-springmvc/wiki/Issue-Submission) if there is something you'd like to see better documented.